# needs to convert Lists of map data into One map

Tags: dart

My question is about dart....

**the result I got**
[{'sam': 8}, {'john': 822}]

**I need to convert it into like below**
{'sam': 8, 'john': 822}

pls help me.
thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void main() {
  final listOfMaps = [
    {'sam': 8},
    {'john': 822},
  ];
  final map = {for (final map in listOfMaps) ...map};
  print(map); // {sam: 8, john: 822}
}
```

**Update after example of data has been uploaded**

I have made the following example which parses the input you have posted as returns the expected data:

```
void main() {
  final map = {
    for (final map in someListOfMaps)
      for (final voted in map['voted']! as List<Map<String, String>>)
        for (final vote in voted.entries) vote.key: int.parse(vote.value)
  };

  print(map);
  // {60e6956078fb6f42da: 1, 60e6956020d8bf42db: 5, 120d8bf42dffsww66: 1, jd58466daa4dw2: 20, gg4c577x6ad8ds6a: 6}
}

const someListOfMaps = [
  {
    "voted": [
      {"60e6956078fb6f42da": "1"},
      {"60e6956020d8bf42db": "5"}
    ],
    "_id": "60e698fe78fb6120d8bf42dd",
    "name": "donald"
  },
  {
    "voted": [
      {"120d8bf42dffsww66": "1"}
    ],
    "_id": "60e698fe78fb6120d8bf42de",
    "name": "barrack"
  },
  {
    "voted": [
      {"jd58466daa4dw2": "20"}
    ],
    "_id": "60e698fe78fb6120d8bf42df",
    "name": "malan"
  },
  {
    "voted": [
      {"gg4c577x6ad8ds6a": "6"}
    ],
    "_id": "60e698fe78fb6120d8bf42e0",
    "name": "kuma"
  }
];
```

Comment: @imeshmadushanka Please tell me if you want a deeper explanation about what the code actually does and what language concepts it uses. I admit that my example is not that clear for beginners but I just wanted to be sure that the solution does what you want before writing a longer explanation.

Comment: my api data..
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/2019imesh/5d1778f8f16b27d110b234a3cc61b10e/raw/447b10dd0ead8fe0e0b58655668f97180843c52d/gistfile1.txt

what I needs in flutter is
the *voted* list of all the data like this as one map
{"60e6956078fb6f42da": "1","60e6956020d8bf42db": "5","120d8bf42dffsww66": "1","jd58466daa4dw2": "20","gg4c577x6ad8ds6a": "6"}

Comment: @imeshmadushanka Ok, I have updated my answer with an example of how to parse the input you have provided. I hope it is clear enough what I am doing to do the parsing. If not, just ask and I will try add some explanation. I also assumed you want the numbers to be parsed into `int` instead of having them as `String`.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2019imesh/60e0339eb78f0985f6bc6d1095a61a6d

can you pls copy the code on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ & refer the error pls

Comment: There are multiple problems in that code. First, `jsonString` is no longer a JSON String but instead just a normal Dart List object containing some structure. Second, your previous example was not valid JSON so I assumed the top structure was a Map but I can see in this new example it is a List which means the solution needs to be changed to work for that. I will update my answer with a working example of your code.

Comment: Thank you brother,
I got the anwer.......highly apreciated your contribution.....

Answer (score 0):

This is a longer approach and probably more understandable.

```
// the result I got [{'sam': 8}, {'john': 822}]
// I need to convert it into like below {'sam': 8, 'john': 822}

void main() {
  final mapList = [{'sam': 8}, {'john': 822}];

  print(mapListToJustMap(mapList)); // output: {sam: 8, john: 822}

  // The <int> is not required
  print(genericMapListToJustMap<int>(mapList)); // output: {sam: 8, john: 822}
}

Map<String, int> mapListToJustMap(List<Map<String, int>> mapList) {
  // Create a new empty map object
  final newMap = <String, int>{};

  // Iterate through the mapList input
  for (final singleMap in mapList) {

    // add the current iteration to the new map object
    newMap.addAll(singleMap);
  }

  return newMap;
}

// A generic approach
Map<String, T> genericMapListToJustMap<T>(List<Map<String, T>> mapList) {
  // Create a new empty map object
  final newMap = <String, T>{};

  // Iterate through the mapList input
  for (final singleMap in mapList) {

    // add the current iteration to the new map object
    newMap.addAll(singleMap);
  }

  return newMap;
}
```

Comment: You should try make that solution more type safe. You don't need to introduce `dynamic` for making this solution. :)

Comment: You could also try make it generic if you want an extra challenge. :)

Comment: my api data.....
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/2019imesh/5d1778f8f16b27d110b234a3cc61b10e/raw/447b10dd0ead8fe0e0b58655668f97180843c52d/gistfile1.txt

what I needs in flutter is
the *voted* list of all the data like this as one map
{"60e6956078fb6f42da": "1","60e6956020d8bf42db": "5","120d8bf42dffsww66": "1","jd58466daa4dw2": "20","gg4c577x6ad8ds6a": "6"}